# Second request doesn't call the callback

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

My method parse_adf_info never is called and I dont know why. No error occurs. I  want to get the links for each ads (parse) and go to ads one by one (parse_ads_urls) and scraping data (parse_ads_info), but this method never is called.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Request, Spider
#from zapimoveis.items import ads_info
from scrapy.selector import Selector
#from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

proxy_list = ["###","###"]

PROXY = "###"


class AdsSpider(Spider):
    name = "zapimoveis"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/",   "https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/oferta/"]

def __init__(self, start_url='', *args, **kwargs):
    super(AdsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.start_urls = []
    self.start_urls.append(start_url)

    self.json = '#{"precomaximo":"2147483647","parametrosautosuggest":[{"B\
                 airro":"JD CAMBURI","Zona":"","Cidade":"VITORIA","Agrupame\
                 nto":"","Estado":"ES"}],"pagina":"%d","ordem":"DataAtualiz\
                 acao","paginaOrigem":"ResultadoBusca","semente":"213739135\
                 0","formato":"Lista"}'

def start_requests(self):
    rq = Request(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse)
    rq.meta['proxy'] = PROXY
    yield rq

def parse(self, response):
    n_pages = response.css('span[class="pull-right num-of"]::text') \
                            .extract_first()
    n_pages = int(n_pages.replace("de ", ""))
    for i in range(1, n_pages+1):
        rq = Request(url=self.start_urls[0]+(self.json % i),
                     callback=self.parse_ads_urls, dont_filter=True)
        rq.meta['proxy'] = PROXY
        yield rq

def parse_ads_urls(self,response):
    for article in response.css('article[class=minificha]'):
        url_to_ads = article.css('a[class=btn-ver-detalhes]::attr(href)')\
                     .extract_first()
        rq2 = Request(url=url_to_ads, callback=self.parse_ads_info,
                      dont_filter=True)
        rq2.meta['proxy'] = proxy_list[0]
        yield rq2

def parse_ads_info(self, response):
    print "#--------->"
    print response.css('span[class=value-ficha]::text').extract_first()
```

I removed my personal proxys.

**(2017-06-06) EDIT 1:**
Output log : https://pastebin.com/4jv2r9um

Comment: Are you sure you get the url_to_ads right? Print it on the console to see if you really scrape it correctly.

Comment: Hi, @CKChen, are u ok? Yes, url_to_ads is like this "https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/oferta/venda+apartamento+2-quartos+jd-camburi+vitoria+es+71m2+RS330000/ID-12681002/?paginaoferta=4
" type (<type 'unicode'>).

Comment: The URL has to be full url with protocol ,like: "http://zapimoveis.com"

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: @CKChen, I dont understand what you say, url_to_ads contains https protocol, just the stack hide it.

Comment: @Granitosaurus, I edited the post and added the log. As you can see, the links to ads lists page is requested, only url in url_to_ads not is requested, and I dont give error, or http status. I'm confused.